# How to avoid UnicodeDecodeError in flask/python?

Tags: python

This error is bugging me in my flask app. The flask is supposed to fetch list of tables from Hbase database and show them. But one particular table shows

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When i print the table contents i got this

```
    [{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}, 
{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b'},
 {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x084'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1'}, 
{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb9'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}, 
{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05^\x84'},
 {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01G'}, 
{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,'}]
```

I tried

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

But then the error changed to

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/nidhin/Hbase/run.py", line 28, in show_table
    return render_template('table.html', Tablename = tablename, tabledatas = tabledata, headers = tabledata[0])
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/templating.py", line 125, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/templating.py", line 107, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/nidhin/Hbase/templates/table.html", line 48, in top-level template code
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

my python code

```
from flask import *
import sys
import happybase

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
app = Flask(__name__)
connection = happybase.Connection('hbase.inzyte.com')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    tables = connection.tables()
    return render_template('tablist.html', tables = tables)


@app.route('/<tablename>')
def show_table(tablename=None):
    print "Entered"
    table = connection.table(tablename)
    print "Connected"
    tabledata = [data for key,data in table.scan()]
    print tabledata
    print "Data collected"
    return render_template('table.html', Tablename = tablename, tabledatas = tabledata, headers = tabledata[0])


app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the html part that displays it

```
  {% for data in tabledatas %}
  <tr>
    {% for value in data.values() %}
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Please help me..

Comment: Don't ever use `sys.setdefaultencoding()`, it *rarely* is the correct way to handle anything. **Where** are you getting that exception, what is the traceback and what code are you using?

Comment: What are those values supposed to represent? Are they perhaps struct-packed integers? They certainly are **not** UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: They are hex values i think.

Comment: No, they are represented as hex by Python because they are non-printable. Some are printable and represented as such (like `,` and `G`) but that doesn't make the value an actual text string. It cannot be decoded to Unicode, because there is nothing there to represent as Unicode.

Comment: You need to think about how you'd represent those values in your template. **What do the values represent**? If they are raw bytes, you need to translate that into something 'readable'. Perhaps use hex characters to represent these, perhaps interpret them as integer numbers, etc. But without context, I cannot make that decision for you, because I have no idea what that data is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the 'c:total' values are integers (as byte arrays) , not strings. Try to use [struct.unpack](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#module-struct) to decode the values

My test code:

```
>>> tabledata = [{'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x084'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa1'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb9'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05^\x84'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01G'}, {'c:total': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,'}]
>>> import struct
>>> for row in tabledata:
        print struct.unpack('>Q', row['c:total'])[0]
0
27
2100
417
185
0
1
351876
327
44
```